# In `ListView`, Why does disabling `animationCache` and `scrollingCache` reduces scroll lag?

Tags: android, performance

I have tried to get more information about the methods in the documentation, but I couldn't find any useful information related to my question.

It seems counter-intuitive that the enabling caching would introduce lag - the purpose of caching is to reduce retrieval latency after all. So what exactly is happening underneath those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrolling cache is basically a drawing cache.

In android, you can ask a View to store its drawing in a cache called drawing cache (basically a bitmap). By default, a drawing cache is disabled because it takes up memory but you can ask the View to explicitly to create one either via setDrawingCacheEnabled or through hardware layers (setLayerType).

So why is it useful? Because using a drawing cache make your animation smooth compared to redrawing the view at every frame.

This type of animation can also be hardware accelerated because the rendering system can take this bitmap and upload it to the GPU as a texture (if using hardware layers) and do fast matrix manipulations on it (like change alpha, translate, rotation). Compare that to doing animation were you are redrawing (onDraw gets called) on every frame.

In the case of a listview, when you scroll by flinging, you are in essence animating the views of your list (either moving them up or down). The listview uses the drawing cache of its visible children (and some potentially visible children near the edges) to animate them very quickly.

Is there a disadvantage to using drawing cache? Yes it consumes memory which is why by default it is turned off for in a View. In the case of ListView, the cache automatically created for you as soon as you touch the ListView and move a little (to differentiate a tap from scroll). In other words, as soon as ListView thinks you are about to scroll/fling it will create a scroll cache for you to animate the scroll/fling motion.

Similary, AnimationCache can be evil sometimes (by evil I mean it increases the frequency of GC)

Defines whether layout animations should create a drawing cache for their children. Enabling the animation cache consumes more memory and requires a longer initialization but provides better performance. The animation cache is enabled by default.

Here's what we did to our list view. First, here's the original list view.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_background_color"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

And here's the one after the change

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_background_color"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false" />
```

You can visit this link

> http://queriesofandroid.blogspot.in/2015/03/in-listview-why-does-disabling.html